# How to keep flex element's width after removing contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have this flexible layout and some JS https://jsfiddle.net/7k8t3xgc/3/

```
<div class="window">

    <div class="left">
         <div class="optional">optional content</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="wordpool"></div>
        <div class="category"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The `.wordpool` element is filled with some words that need to be moved to the `.category` element by clicking on them.

What is happening now, is that the `.window` element is shrinking in width when you click the words. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? Only way I can think of is to calculate wordpools width on render and set it into a style attribute, but it has its drawbacks with responsiveness.

I can't remove the flex functionality, because both left (optional) and right panels need to be same width and centered.

I can't use static width as it needs to be responsive.

It can't be something like `.window { width: 90%; }` because of short content looking silly on wide screens.

Both left and right content changes between pages in my app (think of a quiz or Google Forms - can be text, can be images, checkboxes, radiobuttons etc.) but the HTML template is the same.

Comment: Do you want it's width to stay fixed at the width it is?

Comment: Yes, you can prevent that with a script, where it sets a min-width after everything is loaded

Comment: @doutriforce the best option would be if it stayed the same width as it comes with when rendered

Comment: @orzech1080, so you want to programatically get it's width? It's size will vary?

Comment: Well the other option is to change your js so it doesn't actually remove the elements. For example, make the words position relative and on click, you simple set its z-index to -1, and you also need to restore the z-index to 0 when clicking in categories

Comment: @doutriforce I was hoping for CSS solution :P I know it's doable with JS, but I want to keep it as a last resort

Comment: No, you can't do that without script

Comment: @orzech1080 you will need js to solve this. Either adding a min-width onload and on resize or do not actually remove the elements and just hide them

Comment: @orzech1080 since the element width is variable, you can't do it purely with CSS.

Comment: @Huangism yeah... I guess I will have to stick to this idea :/ Although I will also have to monitor window.resize for this concept to be reliable

Comment: What _drawback with responsiveness_ do you mean when to set the width on load using script?

Comment: @orzech1080 Yes as I mentioned before, you will need to set width when resizing, at the least you will want to check when the viewport size is smaller than your box + whatever other behaviour is needed when resizing to a large size window

Comment: @orzech1080 No need to catch the resize event, I updated with a better solution

Comment: Please review and comment on any answer, and let us know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want it to be dynamic, based on the actual text width on load, add this line to your script

```
$(".window").css('min-width', $(".window").width() + 'px');
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7k8t3xgc/5/)

---

Instead of monitoring the resize event for smaller screens, you can do like this instead

*Note, the `width: 100%` needs to be set using the script, if set in CSS, the calculation will be wrong*

```
$(".window").css({'max-width':$(".window").width() + 'px','width':'100%'});
```

[Updated fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/7k8t3xgc/6/)

Comment: I was hoping for a pure CSS solution, but i guess I'll have to stick to JS :/

Comment: This solution just needs some resize tweaks then it should do the trick

Comment: @Huangism No need to catch the resize event, I updated with a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide another solution, that may or not be what you want:

Don't change the elements from container, just have them on both containers, and toggle the opacity.

You can rearrange them using flexbox and order

```js
var buttons = [{
    name: "lorem"
  },
  {
    name: "ipsum"
  },
  {
    name: "dolor"
  },
  {
    name: "sit"
  },
  {
    name: "amet"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (b of buttons) {
    $('.wordpool').append($("<span>", {
      class: "word",
      id: b.name
    }).html(b.name));
    $('.category').append($("<span>", {
      class: "word hidden",
      id: b.name
    }).html(b.name));
  }

  $(".wordpool").on("click", "span", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    $(".category #" + $(this).attr('id')).toggleClass('hidden');
  });

  $(".category").on("click", "span", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    $(".wordpool #" + $(this).attr('id')).toggleClass('hidden');
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".showoptional", function() {
    $(".left").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f4efdc;
}

.showoptional {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.window {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}

.left {
  display: none;
}

.optional {
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 5px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  order: 99;
}

.wordpool {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.category {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.category .word {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <input type="button" class="showoptional" value="Trigger optional content" />

  <div class="window">

    <div class="left">
      <div class="optional">optional content</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <div class="wordpool"></div>
      <div class="category"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That also was one of my ideas in the beginning. It doesn't really suit me though, because in my original app the words are actually draggable (handled by 3rd party plugin), so I would need to add some more logic into it, like cloning instead of dragging, handling 'drag back into wordpool' event etc. It's not really a problem, can be done in 10 minutes, but I dunno... I guess I was hoping for cleaner solution ;)